# Using pd.cut & pd.vales_count then results as 2d array

Tags: python, pandas, list

Use case

1. I get random observations from a population.
2. Then I group them by bin using pd.cut
3. Then I extract values with pd.values_counts
4. I want to get the calculated interval labels and the frequency count
5. I want to 'glue' the labels column to the frequency counts column to get 2d array (with 2 columns, and n interval rows)
6. I want to convert 2d array to a list for COM interop.

I am close to desired output but I am Python newbie so some smart guy can optimize my label code.

The problem here is the constraint of the final output which needs to be a list so it can be marshalled via COM interop layer to Excel VBA.

```
import inspect
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import skewnorm

pop = skewnorm.rvs(0, size=20)
bins=[-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5]
bins2 = np.array(bins)
bins3 = pd.cut(pop,bins2)
bins4 = [0]*(bins2.size-1)

#print my own labels, doh!
idx=0
for binLoop in bins3.categories:
    intervalAsString="(" + str(binLoop.left)+ "," + str(binLoop.right)+"]" 
    print (intervalAsString)
    bins4[idx]=intervalAsString
    idx=idx+1


table = pd.value_counts(bins3, sort=False)

joined = np.vstack((bins4,table.tolist()))

print (joined)
```

Target output a 2d array convertible to a list

```
|  (-5, -4]  |  0  |
|  (-4, -3]  |  0  |
|  (-3, -2]  |  0  |
|  (-2, -1]  |  1  |
|  (-1, 0]   |  3  |
|  (0, 1]    |  9  |
|  (1, 2]    |  4  |
|  (2, 3]    |  2  |
|  (3, 4]    |  1  |
|  (4, 5]    |  0  |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following should do what you are after:

```
pop = skewnorm.rvs(0, size=20)
bins = range(-5, 5)
binned = pd.cut(pop, bins)

# create the histogram data
hist = binned.value_counts()

# hist is a pandas series with a categorical index describing the bins
# `index.astype(str)` will convert the categories to strings.
hist.index = hist.index.astype(str)

# `.reset_index()` will turn the index into an ordinary column
# `.values` gives you the underlying numpy array
# `tolist()` converts the numpy array to a native python list o' lists.
print(hist.reset_index().values.tolist())
```